# Shared and local variables C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to implement solution for readers writer problem in file system i'm developing. I was searching on the internet and found out this [Wikipedia solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem). Since I'm told no starving may exist I chose third solution. Now, I'm new in multithreaded programming and I have one question. How do I sepparate shared and local variables? I wanted to instantiate one ReadersWriters class in every file object that would manage accessing to that file, so every thread need to have it's own prev and current local variables and all of them need to share nreaders variable. I want to place them in ReadersWriters class.

Comment: What do you mean separate them? Do you have some example code of what you're attempting to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are only two ways for the parent thread to share data with a child thread.

1. Global Variables
2. Passing it via a pointer during creation of the child thread.

Obviously new pointers may be tacked onto any existing objects.

Local variables with remain thread local unless you do something to prevent them from being so. Remember that each thread will have its own stack.